# Farseer Physics: Ways to create a Body?

Tags: xna, c#, algorithm, box2d, farseer-physics-engine

I want to create something similar to this using farsser and Kinect:

https://vimeo.com/33500649

This is my implementation until now:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GlIvJRhco4U

I have the outline vertices and the triangulation of the user. And following the Texture to Polygonmsample i used this line to create the shape, where farseerObject is a list of vertices of the triangles:

_compound = BodyFactory.CreateCompoundPolygon(World, farseerObject, 1f, BodyType.Dynamic);

But I have to update the body each frame (like 30 fps) and this is very slow. I get just 2 or 3 fps.

**There's another (faster) way to create the Body from a list of triangles or the contour vertices?**

How do you think they do this on Box2D?

## Update:

After some testings i used EdgeShapes for the user contour (without triangulation) and i update the vertices for that edges in the fixtures every frame, now all is faster.

```
((EdgeShape)(farseerBody.FixtureList[i].Shape)).Vertex1 = new Vector2(farseerVertices[i].X, farseerVertices[i].Y);
```

**But the collisions does not work!**

My approach is incorrect?

Comment: Are you creating the whole thing every frame? Might be running a little slow if you create huge amounts of garbage perhaps? In that case just try to recycle the same objects instead.

Comment: Do you see the video? The user contour is created every frame, so the vertices are differents. There are some Body type that I can recycle? <br/> This is another example in Box2D http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPWKx3KAvTI

Comment: Until i know, farseer physics is "based" on box2d. There must be a way to do this. I feel that i missing something obvious or not?

Comment: why you need to triangulate if you are just using the overall shape?

Comment: Because the object needs to be convex, or not? I did a test using the ear clipping algorithm and a get up to 10fps, not much better...

Comment: Yes farseer is based on Box2D but in some cases you may need to take into account the diferences of c++ and c#. I don't know the specific reason for why you get so few frames but I thought that maybe might be because a lot of garbage is generated. Have you tried profiling at all?

Comment: Looking into the Farseer source code, the problem appears when the fixtures are created. Now i'm looking for the way to reuse the fixtures. Maybe redifining theirs child shapes.

Comment: Try calling step(0) after changing the shape and before your step(timeDelta).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Finally works!**

I had the vertices of the contour as a sequence, so the solution was use the LoopShape to create the fixture of the body. I did not even know that Class =P

```
 LoopShape loopShape = new LoopShape(farseerVertices);
 //Delete the previous fixture
 farseerBody.DestroyFixture(previousFixture);
 //Create new fixture with the new contour
 farseerBody.CreateFixture(loopShape);
```

And that's all!